# rails 5 nested resource deletion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-resources

I am trying to delete a `Comment` which is a nested resource of the `Post` object.

I receive this message:

> ActionController::ParameterMissing in CommentsController#destroy param
>   is missing or the value is empty: comment

Extracted source:

```
def comments_params
  ActionController::Parameters.permit_all_parameters = true
  params.required(:comment).permit(:author,:body)
end
```

here is the code:

```
def destroy
    @comment.destroy
end

def comments_params
  ActionController::Parameters.permit_all_parameters = true
  params.required(:comment).permit(:author,:body)
end
```

and in the view (partial `_comment.html.erb` called from `post` `show.html.erb`):

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy Comment', [comment.post,comment],
    method: :delete,
    data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

Request parameters are:

> {"_method"=>"delete",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
>   "post_id"=>"test-2", "id"=>"3"}

I tried to add the different parameters in the `comments_param` method but it does not help solving the issue.

Thanks

Comment: does this look like a valid post_id to you? "post_id"=>"test-2"

Comment: the post_id is because of the friendly_id gem, even if the post_id is equal to "2" same result happens.

Answer (score 0):

after find comment then after destroy specific comment.

```
    before_filter :find_comment, :only => [:destroy]

    def destroy
      @comment.destroy
    end

    def find_comment
      @comment = Comment.get(params[:id])
    end

    private

    def comments_params
      params.required(:comment).permit(:author,:body)
    end
```